# ToggleButton getting updated for all the ListView items

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-togglebutton

I have a `ListView` that consists of `ToggleButton` for each row. That `ToggleButton` is basically a favorites button. First, I go and check into the database if a particular value exists, if yes, I display the button as red else grey. The issue is whenever I click on any button, all the buttons turn red or vice versa and by default also on scrolling all the buttons get updated. My adapter code is:

```
public class PostAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PostModel> {
    Drawable mDrawable;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public PostAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PostModel> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //Get the date item for this position
        final PostModel postModel = getItem(position);
        boolean isClicked = false;

        //Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate a new view from custom_row layout
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            //Casting of views from the custom_row layout
            viewHolder.tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            viewHolder.tvPost = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPost);
            viewHolder.imageIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageIcon);
            viewHolder.toggleButton = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myHeartToggleButton);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //Filling each views values
        viewHolder.tvTitle.setText(postModel.getTitle());
        viewHolder.tvPost.setText(postModel.getPost());
        viewHolder.imageIcon.setImageResource(postModel.getAssociatedDrawable());

        final DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(getContext().getApplicationContext());
        dbHelper.open();

        if (dbHelper.isClickedPost(postModel.getTitle())) {
            Drawable mDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext().getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.favorite_icon);
            mDrawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
            viewHolder.toggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawable);
            isClicked = true;
        } else {
            viewHolder.toggleButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext().getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.favorite_icon));
        }

        final boolean finalIsClicked = isClicked;

        viewHolder.toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    if (!finalIsClicked) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), "Clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), "Clicked again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), "Hello...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvTitle, tvPost;
        ImageView imageIcon;
        ToggleButton toggleButton;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First:

You have to place the `toggleButton` itself inside the  `viewHolder`. Like this:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvTitle, tvPost;
    ImageView imageIcon;
    ToggleButton toggleButton;
}
```

Then change this line:

```
toggleButton = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myHeartToggleButton);
```

To:

```
viewHolder.toggleButton = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myHeartToggleButton);
```

Also, in other places instead of `toggleButton` use `viewHolder.toggleButton`.

The other thing to note is that the `isClicked` also shouldn't be placed inside the adapter because it holds a different value for each row.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, I have already tried that. It gives me the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure? Because it really seems to be causing the problem. Can I see your edited code?

Comment: You have to keep in mind that the Viewholder is used to keep track of the views for each row (item). In the above code, you're storing the toggleButton of every row in one variable.

Comment: I have updated the code. And the problem still continues.@Behzad